# Xamarin FFImageLoading.CachedImage not displaying at first time

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm having some troubleshotting with FFImageLoading on xamarin,  what is happening is that  the image only  seems to be displaying when the page realoads for the second time  (exemple, I leave  the page than press back button)
I already tried to  load  these images first  before be loading the ContentPage be created, but it didn't work.
I tried to  ForceLayout to  display  it but  it didn't work  as  well though.

here's my follow code  in the view

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell Tapped="OnDetailsButtonClicked">
        <Frame
            Margin="2,2,2,2"
            Padding="5"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            IsClippedToBounds="True">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                    x:Name="profilePhoto"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Source="{Binding CoworkerProfilePhoto}"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="50">
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                        <fftransformations:CircleTransformation />
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                ....
```

As you  can  see  the file is being bided by  the CoworkerProfilePhoto variable on my  biding  list.

these image are being stored on the device and then showing on the screen,  it's a simple file saving

```
public async static Task SaveImagem(this byte[] imagem, String nomeArquivo, IFolder pastaRaiz = null)
```

{
    IFolder pasta = pastaRaiz ?? FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

```
IFile arquivo = await pasta.CreateFileAsync(nomeArquivo, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

using (System.IO.Stream stream = await arquivo.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
{
    stream.Write(imagem, 0, imagem.Length);
}
```

}

Any Idea ?
I checked these two links

https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/238

https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/41/41087/bug.html

That seems to be related, but none of them worked too.

Comment: Does it work with a normal Image control instead of ffimageloading:CachedImage?

Comment: I tried using  Image, but it didn't work  though, I guess  it is because  the image is being loaded asyncrously, but not pretty  sure, maybe I'm not using or doing it  right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found  a solution that  worked propely  for me
The  first problem was  that  I was biding only the file name  in my CoworkerProfilePhoto property

As shown bellow

```
item.CoworkerProfilePhoto =  photo.Name;
```

but it was impossible for the system to  find where the file was stored so
i had to  pass the absolute Uri file path.

As shown bellow

```
var folder = PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.GetFolderAsync(myPath).Result;
item.CoworkerProfilePhoto = new Uri(folder.Path + "/" + photo.Name, UriKind.Absolute);
```

Comment: You can mark it as the right answer later so that we can help more people with same problem:).